# Primefaces overlay panel: "showCloseIcon" is not working

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Hi I am using an overlay panel to display a PDF. When I click on the close button, the PDF is still open. Here's my code:

```
    <p:commandButton id="view" value="View" type="button" />

      <p:overlayPanel id="pdf" for="view" hideEffect="Explode"  dynamic="true" showCloseIcon="true"  >
            <p:media value="/file/sample.pdf" player="pdf"> 
                    Your browser can't display pdf,<h:outputLink value="/file/Payslip_User_Guide.pdf">Click</h:outputLink> to download PDF.
            </p:media>
      </p:overlayPanel>
```

I try using dismissable, and it does not work. Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of PrimeFaces you are using but according to [PrimeFaces 5.0 showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlayPanel.jsf) the following code should work:

```
  <p:overlayPanel id="viewPanel" for="viewBtn" hideEffect="explode" dynamic="true" dismissable="false" showCloseIcon="true">
        <!-- content goes here -->
  </p:overlayPanel>
```

What do mean with "the pdf is still open"? The overlayPanel doesn't disappear at all, is that right?

Comment: Yes the pdf is still open. I am using Primefaces 4.0. I think its a javascript library which is causing this issue.

Comment: Yeah, I took a look at the PF 4.0 documentation. Your code Looks fine. Seems like something else instead of PrimeFaces is causing the trouble. Can you provide your whole page?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but today I came across this problem and I could fix it, so maybe it can help other people.

It may be a problem of jQuery. If you use Bootstrap, you will have imported jQuery but PrimeFaces has jQuery included, so there is a conflict of jQuery versions. Remove bootstrap jQuery and use the one of PrimeFaces. It worked for me.